# .vbs Help me loop this through a directory

Tags: vbscript, windows-scripting

I have written a script that works. What it does now is it looks through a directory to a given file and returns what is on the second row fourth tab (RXC193) and renames the file to that of which it found from a file like this:

@Program    @RxBIN  @RXPCN  @RxGroup    @MemberID   @WebsiteE   @WebsiteS   @VerticalLogo   @TextLogo
RXCUT   013824  RXCUT   RXC193  RXC5FHXF9   www.rxcut.com/HBG   www.rxcut.com/HBG/es            P:\RxCut\In Design Implementation\RXC193

What I need this script to be able to do is loop through the directory and rename all files by this RXC#####. Here is the script:

```
Call TwoDimensionArrayTest

Sub TwoDimensionArrayTest
' Version 1.0
' Writtem by Krystian Kara
' Dated 25-Jan-2009


    Dim fso
    Dim oFile
    Dim arrline
    Dim arrItem
    Dim objFolder
    Dim i
    Dim arrMain()
    Dim sFileLocation, strResults

    Const forReading = 1

' The file contains on each line:
    ' Text1 (tab) Text2 (tab) Text3 (tab) Text4
    ' Text5 (tab) Text6 (tab) Text7 (tab) Text8
'etc etc


    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        sFileLocation = "file 2.txt"

        Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFileLocation, forReading, False)

    Do While oFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        strResults = oFile.ReadAll
    Loop

' Close the file
    oFile.Close

' Release the object from memory
    Set oFile = Nothing

' Return the contents of the file if not Empty
    If Trim(strResults) <> "" Then

        ' Create an Array of the Text File
        arrline = Split(strResults, vbNewLine)
    End If

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrline)
        If arrline(i) = "" Then
            ' checks for a blank line at the end of stream
            Exit For
        End If 

        ReDim Preserve arrMain(i)

            arrMain(i) = Split(arrline(i), vbTab)

    Next

    fso.MoveFile "file 2.txt", arrMain(1)(3) & ".txt"

End Sub ' TwoDimensionArrayTest
```

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to parameterize the file name in your sub-procedure so it can be called multiple times for different files, like this:

```
Sub TwoDimensionArrayTest(fileName) 'you may want a more descriptive name

    ' ...
    sFileLocation = fileName
    ' ...

End Sub
```

Then, write a loop that goes through your directory, calling your sub each time around:

```
Dim fso, folder

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("Your Folder Name")
For Each file In folder.Files
    TwoDimensionArrayTest file.Path
Next
```

Comment: I keep getting invalid call procedure

Comment: You should also remove your `Call TwoDimensionArrayTest` line since after my suggested change, `TwoDimensionArrayTest` requires a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Final Error free code! Finally have it searching through my directory of Tab-delimited.txt files and grabbing from the second row third tab (group number) then renaming the files to its corrisponding group number! YAY!

heres final error free code!:

```
Call TwoDimensionArrayTest
```

Sub TwoDimensionArrayTest

Dim fso
    Dim oFile
    Dim arrline
    Dim arrItem
    Dim i
    Dim arrMain()
    Dim sFileLocation, strResults

```
Const forReading = 1
```

strFolder = "C:\Documents and Settings\jmituzas.NMCLLC\Desktop\desktop2\New Folder (2)\datafiles"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder).Files
    If Right(LCase(objFile.Name), 4) = LCase(".txt") Then

```
    ' The file contains on each line:
' Text1 (tab) Text2 (tab) Text3 (tab) Text4
' Text5 (tab) Text6 (tab) Text7 (tab) Text8
```

'etc etc

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        sFileLocation = objFile.Name

```
    Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(objFile.Name, forReading, False)

Do While oFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    strResults = oFile.ReadAll
Loop

' Close the file
oFile.Close
```

' Release the object from memory
    Set oFile = Nothing

' Return the contents of the file if not Empty
    If Trim(strResults) <> "" Then

```
    ' Create an Array of the Text File
    arrline = Split(strResults, vbNewLine)
End If

For i = 0 To UBound(arrline)
    If arrline(i) = "" Then
        ' checks for a blank line at the end of stream
        Exit For
    End If 

    ReDim Preserve arrMain(i)

        arrMain(i) = Split(arrline(i), vbTab)

Next

  fso.MoveFile sFileLocation, arrMain(1)(3) & ".txt"
```

End If 
 Next
End Sub ' TwoDimensionArrayTest