# How to print multiple html files on Windows 8 with VBS

Tags: html, batch-file, pdf, printing

I have a folder containing 1650 HTML files that, due to local authorities, must be also printed in paper form.

I have tried with classic ctrl+A (even if I was trying on smaller quantities) and then I have looked for PRINT label in the right click menu, but there's any.

If I choose to print multiple jpg or pdf files, the PRINT voice appears.

How am I supposed to print multiple html files? A batch file? (I have no knowledge about how to).

I have also thought to convert html to pdf, but had no success with PDF Creator and PDF Architect.

Any of you with some experience to share?
I have wrtten some code mixing the one given by Tim and what I found on stackoverflow, but had no success.

Here it is:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  objStartFolder = "C:\Users\mainUser\Desktop\ft"

  Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
  Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

  For Each objFile in colFiles
  strFileName = objFile.Name

  If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "html" Then

        On Error Resume Next

        Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
        Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
        Const PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2

        Dim objExplorer
        Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        objExplorer.Navigate objFolder.Path +"\"+ objFile.Name
        objExplorer.Visible = 1

        Do while objExplorer.ReadyState <> 4
            WScript.Sleep 1000 'milliseconds
        Loop

        oIExplorer.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER

  End If

  Next
```

It just opens one html in internet explorer. I thought it would have open all the files, and already in PRINT "mode". 
I think I am missing something.

Comment: It could be a programming question but what happens if you open Printers and drag'n'drop the selected files from the Explorer window onto the printer icon?

Comment: Here's a link to "How to convert HTML to PDF" http://www.win2pdf.com/doc/index.html?html-to-pdf.htm

Comment: Converting file by file? It's easier to open each html file with browser and then print it. Is there the chance to make a bulk conversion of html files into pdf's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this thread for looping through files in a directory: [How to do something to each file in a directory with a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script)

Then you can use the native `PRINT` command so your batch file could be as simple as this:

`for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b c:\') do PRINT %%f`

---

In light of the comments below:

---

Ahh. Then you will likely have to automate IE to print the page. Play with a VBScript along these lines:

```
Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
Const PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2

objStartFolder = "C:\Users\mainUser\Desktop\ft"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    strFileName = objFile.Name
    If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "html" Then
        handle = objExplorer.Hwnd
        objExplorer.Navigate objFolder.Path + "\" + objFile.Name

        For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
            If handle = Wnd.Hwnd Then Set objExplorer = Wnd
        Next

        Do While objExplorer.Busy
            WScript.Sleep 1000 'milliseconds
        Loop

        objExplorer.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
    End If
Next
Set oShell = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objExplorer = Nothing
```

### 3rd Update:

I fixed the code above. I apologize.Its been some time since I've worked with IE. Apparently IE treats each tab as a new instance of IE, and loading a document "creates" a new tab. As a result, we have to load the page and then find our IE window again so we can set it back to the variable.

Comment: You won't be happy with the output of the `print` command as it is intended to print _text_ files, so you'll print the HTML source text...

Comment: I have tried this, but with no success. I have changed the folder where the files are, but nothing happens. What is wrong with it? Here it is my bat file:     `for /f %%f in ('dir /b C:\Users\mainUser\Desktop\ric\') do echo %%f`

Comment: thank @aschipfl ! No, I need to print fomratted html page indeed, not the source code of it.

Comment: @Tlm Thank you very much. Just one stuipd question....where am I supposed to code that snippet of yours? Where the vbscript should be placed and how to launch it? Moreover, I cannot see any recursiveness in that script. It seems to process one file at a time, doesn't it? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @Aptivus, A VBScript is a .txt (text) file with a .vbs file extension. Create a new text document and paste the code in there, then change the extension to .vbs. And no, there is no looping in my code. Looping through the files in a directory is a pretty basic task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665748/vbscript-to-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200028/vbscript-list-all-pdf-files-in-folder-and-subfolders or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620773/vbs-help-me-loop-this-through-a-directory

Comment: Thank you  @Tim I will try it in the next few hours

Comment: Hello @Tim, I tried mixing some vbs, but it only opens just one html file. I am not sure I did it wright. Please see my editing in my post. Thank you very much.

Comment: It works! At least with 5 files at a time. 5+ Explorer crashes :(

Comment: Just a thought (since it crashes after 5 printings), I wonder if you could create a 2 part process to speed this up. The first part being a batch file that would loop through the files in the directory and pass each file to a VBScript (the 2nd part) that would then print the passed file. It might be much faster, and it would essentially be a  multi-threaded app (since each new instance of the printing script would/should be a new thread). **However** it could potentially kill you printer and/or print spool since that is most likely your biggest bottleneck.

Comment: One more thought: If these files get created a semi-regularly, you could modify the script to copy them to a "Completed" folder after the page is printed. Then set the script up as a scheduled task that runs once a week/month. Then all you have to do is pick them up at the printer. (I work hard to be lazy)

Comment: Nice thoughts indeed! Probelm is, as you may have noticed, I am no expert at VBS. As to your second thought, luckily this process of mass printing will be no more needed. I had some mods on the system, so it now generates a big pdf that can be sent to printer once a month, printing no more than 150 pages per time.